# If hypothethically a car tries to go in two different directions at the same time, which direction will it end up going?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, vectors, velocity

When we add two vectors(**A** and **B**), we get one resultant sum vector(**C**).
*i.e.* adding two different directions gives us one resultant direction.

So in the same way if a hypothetical car was trying to go in two different directions at the same time somehow , can the direction it will end up going  be figured out by simply adding up those two directions(the two vectors)?

[image]

Comment: Note that your vector drawing is inaccurate. And, a car would do exactly the same thing (but, contrary to your drawing, it cannot dig itself into the ground, or fly).

Comment: How does it go two directions at the same time? Maybe a spaceship can have two different jets and accelerate in two directions at the same time and the net acceleration is the vector sum.

Comment: @EricDavidKramer What is the (conceptual) difference between moving in two different directions and accelerating in two different directions? I see no difference for your spaceship to move both horizontally and vertically with net movement being vector sum, just as it can accelerate both horizontally and vertically with net acceleration being the vector sum. In both cases there is just one "real" vector, which can be decomposed into several  pieces.

Comment: So your question is a vector question, not a car question, because you can't actually do that with a car.

Comment: @EricDavidKramer If that was answer to me, neither you can accelerate in two different directions. You can apply force in two different directions, not accelerate.

Comment: @Umaxo, Have you ever answered the question, "What is the X or Y or Z _component_ of the acceleration?" It's the same thing. If the acceleration of a particle is $\vec{a}$, there may be some mathematically valid reason why it helps you to solve a problem if you _decompose_ the acceleration into the sum of $\vec{a_1}+\vec{a_2}+\dots$ such that they all add up to $\vec{a}$ and one or more of them points in some significant direction or has some significant magnitude.

Comment: @Umaxo You're right

Comment: How can a car try to go in two different directions?

Comment: @BioPhysicist I meant a hypothetical car and not a real world one .But Thanks for pointing it out as now i have mentioned it now in the question itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In place of a car I am going to give you an example of an electron .

Suppose there is an electron going in the positive X direction with some speed $v$ . It enters a region of uniform magnetic field whose direction is into the plane of this screen ( as shown in fig)

[image]

From Lorentz force formula , we know that the electron will experience a force perpendicular to the direction of its velocity. The electron will start following a curved path . Same is true with a ball tied with a string and rotated in a circular motion

[image]

The electron and the ball used in the above examples followed a curved path which is due to the resultant direction . So we saw that if something is given speed in two directions it always go on their resultant direction.

Comment: yes I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused as to *how* exactly the car is trying to go in two different directions; maybe its wheels are misaligned? In that case, it will experience *forces* in two different directions.
You can then take the vector resultant of the forces to get a net force, and the car will be accelerated in that direction.

Comment: I meant a hypothetical car and not a real world one .But Thanks for pointing it out as now i have mentioned it now in the question itself.

Comment: Even hypothetically, its unclear what it means to try to go in two directions at once. The only explanation i can think of is that it's experiencing forces in two different directions.